How to disable Tab triggering `ls` and list of suggestions in oh-my-zsh?
How can I disable the feature in oh-my-zsh where pressing tab triggers ls (list directory)?

Similarly, when typing certain characters like c or g and then hitting tab, I'm also getting zsh: do you wish to see all X possibilities (Y lines)? For the other characters it just prints them without asking.

This is triggered every time I press tab. Weirdly, I can't even use it. Pressing tab or arrow down a second time does not go through the list of files/folders.
It is extremely annoying because it interferes with the zsh-autosuggestions plugin.
What I've tried
I tried various things including:

adding unsetopt AUTO_CD autocd AUTO_MENU MENU_COMPLETE CDABLE_VARS AUTO_NAME_DIRS to my .zshrc. None worked.
re-installing oh-my-zsh completely (because I thought it was triggered by the zsh-autocomplete plugin)

I first thought this was due to the zsh-autocomplete plugin I installed, but I have long uninstalled all remnants of this plugin.
Other links

found a related question here on Stack Overflow where someone wanted to limit this list to directories (and exclude files)
posted an issue about this on the ohmyzsh GitHub repo
related ohmyzsh GitHub issue discussing settings of the zsh-autocomplete plugin
this Stack Overflow user had a similar issue but just wanted to change the shortcut of the autocomplete. (This educated me that I can press arrow right to accept zsh-autosuggestions)


I took the liberty to add the zsh-completion tag to your question, because from what I know, you need to use some zstyle commands to configure this. I don't think that you are supposed to somehow "select" the entries from your list with the help of your cursor keys.  simply triggers the completion system.
